# Facing relation "base_post" does not exist LINE 1: ..., "base_post"."featured", "base_post"."slug" FROM "base_post... issue. Can anybody help me?

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

Recently, I'm working with my Django Portfolio and after successfully deploying on Heroku I faced this error

```
LINE 1: ..., "base_post"."featured", "base_post"."slug" FROM "base_post...
```

So, this is how complete error is looking like

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://shubhajeet-pradhan.herokuapp.com/

Django Version: 3.0.8
Python Version: 3.10.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'shubhajeet_portfolio',
 'base.apps.BaseConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django_filters',
 'ckeditor',
 'ckeditor_uploader',
 'storages',
 'cloudinary_storage']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /app/base/templates/base/index.html, error at line 171
   relation "base_post" does not exist
LINE 1: ..., "base_post"."featured", "base_post"."slug" FROM "base_post...
                                                             ^

   161 :        </div>
   162 :    </section>
   163 : 
   164 :    <section class="s1">
   165 :        <div class="main-container">
   166 :            <div class="greeting-wrapper">
   167 :            <h3 style="text-align: center;">Projects</h3>
   168 :                <div class="blog-wrapper">
   169 :                    {% include 'base/navbar_blog.html' %}
   170 :            <div class="post-wrapper">
   171 :                 {% for post in posts %} 
   172 :                <div>
   173 :                    <div class="post">
   174 :                        <img class="thumbnail" src="{{post.thumbnail.url}}">
   175 :                        <div class="post-preview">
   176 :                            <h6 class="post-title">{{post.headline}}</h6>
   177 :                            <p class="post-intro">{{post.sub_headline}}</p>
   178 :                            <a href="{%  url 'post' post.slug %}">Read More</a>
   179 :                        </div>
   180 :                    </div>
   181 :                </div>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "base_post" does not exist
LINE 1: ..., "base_post"."featured", "base_post"."slug" FROM "base_post...
                                                             ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/app/base/views.py", line 26, in home
    return render(request, 'base/index.html', context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 166, in render
    len_values = len(values)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1152, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /
Exception Value: relation "base_post" does not exist
LINE 1: ..., "base_post"."featured", "base_post"."slug" FROM "base_post...
```

**and this is my views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.conf import settings
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import logout, login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .decorators import *

from .forms import PostForm, CustomUserCreationForm, ProfileForm, UserForm
from .filters import PostFilter

from .models import *


# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(active=True, featured=True)[0:6]

    context = {'posts': posts}
    return render(request, 'base/index.html', context)


def posts(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(active=True)
    myFilter = PostFilter(request.GET, queryset=posts)
    posts = myFilter.qs

    page = request.GET.get('page')

    paginator = Paginator(posts, 6)

    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {'posts': posts, 'myFilter': myFilter}
    return render(request, 'base/posts.html', context)


def post(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        PostComment.objects.create(
            author=request.user.profile,
            post=post,
            body=request.POST['comment']
        )
        messages.success(request, "You're comment was successfully posted!")

        return redirect('post', slug=post.slug)

    context = {'post': post}
    return render(request, 'base/post.html', context)


def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'base/profile.html')


# CRUD VIEWS
@admin_only
@login_required(login_url="home")
def createPost(request):
    form = PostForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('posts')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'base/post_form.html', context)


@admin_only
@login_required(login_url="home")
def updatePost(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    form = PostForm(instance=post)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('posts')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'base/post_form.html', context)


@admin_only
@login_required(login_url="home")
def deletePost(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        post.delete()
        return redirect('posts')
    context = {'item': post}
    return render(request, 'base/delete.html', context)


def sendEmail(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        template = render_to_string('base/email_template.html', {
            'name': request.POST['name'],
            'email': request.POST['email'],
            'message': request.POST['message'],
        })

        email = EmailMessage(
            request.POST['subject'],
            template,
            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            ['shubhajeet.pradhan12@gmail.com']
        )

        email.fail_silently = False
        email.send()

    return render(request, 'base/email_sent.html')


def loginPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        # Little Hack to work around re-building the usermodel
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            user = authenticate(request, username=user.username, password=password)
        except:
            messages.error(request, 'User with this email does not exists')
            return redirect('login')

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Email/Password is incorrect')

    context = {}
    return render(request, 'base/login.html', context)


def registerPage(request):
    form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Account successfully created!')

            user = authenticate(request, username=user.username, password=request.POST['password1'])

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)

            next_url = request.GET.get('next')
            if next_url == '' or next_url == None:
                next_url = 'home'
            return redirect(next_url)
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'An error has occurred with registration')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'base/register.html', context)


def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')


@login_required(login_url="home")
def userAccount(request):
    profile = request.user.profile

    context = {'profile': profile}
    return render(request, 'base/account.html', context)


@login_required(login_url="home")
def updateProfile(request):
    user = request.user
    profile = user.profile
    form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()

        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('account')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'base/profile_form.html', context)
```

**Ths is my models.py file**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.utils.text import slugify
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images", default="/user.png")
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        name = str(self.first_name)
        if self.last_name:
            name += ' ' + str(self.last_name)
        return name


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sub_headline = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images", default="/images/placeholder.png")
    body = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if self.slug is None:
            slug = slugify(self.headline)

            has_slug = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()
            count = 1
            while has_slug:
                count += 1
                slug = slugify(self.headline) + '-' + str(count)
                has_slug = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()

            self.slug = slug

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class PostComment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body

    @property
    def created_dynamic(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now
```

Can anybody help me out from this problem ?

**Any suggestions or solutions would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it works on your computer,but not in heroku. It may be problem with data base.
Try to `makemigrations` and `migrate`. Check that this base post is exist in data base in development.
You could try to add some exception in html, like:

```
{% if posts %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <your code>
{% else %}
    <p>We have not any posts</p>
{% ednif %}
```

Comment: I tried this also but not working and since you've mentioned about database problem then sorry I haven't mentioned that I'm using MongoDB. So, is there any problem because of this. On my local machine everything is working properly(as you've mentioned) but not on Heroku.

Comment: As I see you haven't this 'base_post' in your code, it should be in data base. Have you tried to go into admin panel and add some posts? Then the cycle in html ```{% for post in posts %}``` could show something. You could enter admin panel even during mistake on other page.

Comment: well ! I've tried that too but failed to open my admin panel also. But now it is showing new error that is 
" relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user... "

Comment: Thanks  buddy ! After answering your question I noticed what I missed. Thanks A lot man 